# Use of apacite package with subfiles package or standalone package results in LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble

Tags: citing, standalone, apa6, subfiles

I want to create a multi-file project for my thesis, in which I use separate files for sections. To be able to compile these separate files I tried using the `subfiles` package and the `standalone` package.

A problem arises when I use one of these packages in conjunction with the `apacite` package. Then, when compiling the `main.tex` file, I get a `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble`. I don't understand why get I this error. It doesn't matter if the `apacite` package is loaded after or before `subfiles` or `standalone`.

Example of `main.tex` and `chapter1.tex` files in case of using `subfiles` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles} 
\begin{document}
text
\cite{xx19xx}
\end{document}
```

Example of `main.tex` and `chapter1.tex` files in case of using standalone package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text
\cite{xx19xx}
\end{document}
```

In both cases I get the previous mentioned error. Is there a way in which I can use `apacite` and still use separate files for my project?

Comment: One other way to compile chapters on its own is to include them with `\include` and then use `\includeonly{<chapterfilename>,...}` to only include those you want. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/2975

Comment: I had a look at this now. The reason is that `\cite` from `apacite` checks if it is in the preamble or not by testing the definition of `\document` (which is the underlying macro behind `\begin{document}`. However, with both packages the definition of `\document` got changes, so that the test thinks its still in the preamble and uses a preamble-only macro (`\AtBeginDocument`) which causes the error. I will code some solution for this and post an answer.

Comment: See also [errors - Problem when using \nocite together with the standalone package - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102234/problem-when-using-nocite-together-with-the-standalone-package/102247#102247) but there's a difference between whether `apacite` package is used so I'll leave it. The cause is pretty-much the same though

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that with `apacite` the `\cite` macro calls `\nocite` which checks if it is in the preamble or not by testing the definition of `\document` (which is the underlying macro behind `\begin{document}`. However, with both packages the definition of `\document` got changed, so that the test always thinks its still in the preamble and uses a preamble-only macro (`\AtBeginDocument`) which causes the error.

---

A way to avoid this with `standalone` is to patch `\nocite` so that it doesn't compare `\@onlypreamble` with `\document` but `\documentclass` with `\sa@documentclass`. This works because `standalone` sets `\documentclass` to `\sa@documentclass` directly at the very end of the preamble by appending the required code to `\document`. <sup>1</sup>

```
% Main document
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for the \patchcmd
\makeatletter
% Patch after apacite got loaded!
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\@onlypreamble\document}{\documentclass\sa@documentclass}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

---

For `subfiles` things are different. Here `\document` is only redefined inside the subfiles itself, so its not possible to patch the test to compare different macros in a way which works both inside and outside subfiles.
Here I would simply replace the test with an always true `\ifx` and never use `\cite` or `\nocite` in the preamble where it doesn't belong anyway.
This patch also works for `standalone`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>) 
<sub>However, the internal test is flawed anyway and should be removed by the `apacite` author. With and without the patch it calls `\AtBeginDocument` inside `\nocite` where `\document` still has its original definition and so it calls `\AtBeginDocument` again and then again ... until TeX runs out of resources and aborts!</sub>

Comment: I now wrote a report to the author of `apacite` to inform him about this issue and the broken inside-preamble test. I suggested to remove the test altogether. The original `\nocite` doesn't work inside the preamble either.