# Combination of Subfiles, Apacite and Babel packages result in LaTeX error

Tags: bibtex, babel, apa-style, subfiles

For my bachelor thesis, I want to write my chapters in separate files and be able to compile them separately. To combine them, I use the `subfiles` package. For citations, I have to use Apa style via the `apacite` package.

As already discussed in [Use of apacite package with subfiles package or standalone package results in LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91200/use-of-apacite-package-with-subfiles-package-or-standalone-package-results-in-la), `apacite` and `subfiles` don't go together well. To fix this problem I use the solution as posted:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This works fine, but I want my reference list to be in English (not in French as is standard with `apacite`). Normally, I use the `babel` package to correct this problem, but with the `subfiles` package this results in the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
l.4 \cite{test}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The code I used:

*main.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % works fine without babel
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1}

% Bibliography:
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{../ref/references} 

\end{document}
```

*chapter1.tex:*

```
\documentclass[./main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
text
\cite{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Thank you! I already used the site a lot, but never registered! @ClaudioFiandrino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen` helps to reveal what's going on.

`babel` saves the old definition of `\nocite` in `\org@nocite`, so either:

1. Patch `\nocite` before loading `babel`, or
2. Patch `\org@nocite` as well, after loading `babel`.

The first is probably the better solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{apacite}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}{\iftrue}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[english]{babel} % works fine without babel

\begin{document}
\subfile{94989-chapter1}

% Bibliography:
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{../ref/references} 

\end{document}
```