# Problem when using \nocite together with the standalone package

Tags: errors, citing, standalone

Given:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{inclusion}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

With:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

And:

```
@book{Bateman.1906,
 author = {Bateman, Newton and Selby, Paul and Short, William F.},
 year = {1906},
 title = {Historical encyclopedia of Illinois},
 address = {Chicago},
 publisher = {Munsell Pub. Co.}
}


@book{Beckett.1966,
 author = {Beckett, J. C.},
 year = {1966},
 title = {The making of modern Ireland, 1603-1623},
 address = {London},
 publisher = {Faber}
}
```

I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot be used in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.5 \nocite{*}
?
```

Yet if I comment out either `\input{inclusion}` or `\nocite{*}` the test compiles without error. I'm running a command line of `latexmk -xelatex test` on Win7 Ultimate. TeX courtesy of MikTeX.

So either I'm doing something egregious or there is something wrong with standalone? Suggestions and brickbats welcome.

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to obtain with this code? What's in `inclusion` file? Why do you want to use `standalone`?

Comment: @Ignasi In posted text the second block is the inclusion file. This is a minimal example of the problem. I use standalone because I have >40 TikZ files that need to be developed independently and this approach allows me to be lazy with regards their development. Or to give myself the benefit, perhaps more efficient rather than lazy...

Comment: This is related to [Use of apacite package with subfiles package or standalone package results in LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91200) and is because the preamble test inside `\nocite` gets confused by the changes done by `standalone`. The solution I posted there should also work with the standard `\nocite`, not just the one of the `apacite` package. I might had a fix for this to `standalone` itself, maybe as an option.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Is it (standalone package) fixed yet? I think something simple such as `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\sa@documentclass}{\global\let\sa@orig@document\document}{}{}
\pretocmd{\sa@document}{\global\let\document\sa@orig@document}{}{}
\makeatother
` would work, is there any disadvantage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to how `\nocite` is defined:

```
% latex.ltx, line 6146:
\def\nocite#1{\@bsphack
  \ifx\@onlypreamble\document
    \@for\@citeb:=#1\do{%
      \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
      \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\G@refundefinedtrue
          \@latex@warning{Citation `\@citeb' undefined}}{}}%
  \else
    \@latex@error{Cannot be used in preamble}\@eha
    % \AtBeginDocument{\nocite{#1}}
  \fi
  \@esphack}
```

and the fact that `standalone` redefines `\document` to be the same as `\sa@document`, which is reasonable from the point of view of this package, but has the effect of breaking `\nocite` because the

```
\ifx\@onlypreamble\document
```

test will return false.

You can fix the problem by providing a test free version of `\nocite` at begin document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}

\makeatletter
\def\@documentnocite#1{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#1\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
    \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\G@refundefinedtrue
      \@latex@warning{Citation `\@citeb' undefined}}{}}%
  \@esphack}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\nocite\@documentnocite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\input{myersinput}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myersbib}
\end{document}
```

A simpler code uses `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd{\nocite}
    {\ifx\@onlypreamble\document}
    {\iftrue}
    {}
    {\@latex@warning@no@line{\string\nocite\space changed, no patch possible}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\input{myersinput}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myersbib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I'll re-write and test and mod this to answer accordingly.

Comment: Tested! I award you the cake and eat it to honor :)

Comment: @hsmyers Send me a slice!

Comment: Virtually speaking---done deal :)

Comment: See also [Use of apacite package with subfiles package or standalone package results in LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94412).